# Slack Sound / Notification Issue With Windows 10, Focus assist is on but its turned off in settings?

Tags: windows-10, slack

I've only recently joined the wide community of people using Slack because I needed to join a workspace for my job. This workspace is amazing and I love slack especially for communication and that's the sole purpose of why I am using it.

I use Slack on my computer and since using it has been great however notifications not coming through with sound are becoming a problem for me. I need to know when certain channels have a new message in them and this is easily done by sound especially when working on two monitors....

When I go into preferences slack alerts me that my focus assist is turned on with a warning message. Then when I go into windows settings focus assist is 
turned off and not on. I researched this issue and tried everything on google ranging from reinstalling slack to turning off and on slack notifications to clearing cache and nothing works except reset app data, however I need to do this every time I turn my computer on, which is an inconvenience and easily forgettable.

If anyone knows a way to fix this properly and not just a temporary fix like I have please can you help and comment down below, I would appreciate it :)

Thanks

Comment: how did you reset app data?

Answer (score 0):

From [Slack's Twitter](https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/1016751499349815296):

Go to Preferences > Notifications > Sound & appearance > Deliver notifications via (dropdown) > Slack's built-in notifications